# What are proto.tab.values and lookups.tab.values, and why does IntelliJ lock them?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to build a mixed Java/Kotlin project, using a Gradle build.  Frequently when I try to build, I get this error:

[image: Could not delete caches dir; filename or extension is too long]

If I try instead to delete the cache folder manually, this happens (wrapped to avoid horizontal scroll):

```
[...]\build\kotlin\compileKotlin>rd caches-jvm /s /q
caches-jvm\jvm\kotlin\proto.tab.values - The process cannot access the file because it is being used 
    by another process.
caches-jvm\lookups\lookups.tab.values - The process cannot access the file because it is being used 
    by another process.
```

It seems like those two files are locked by IntelliJ, because if I exit IntelliJ and then remove the caches-jvm folder, it works.

What are these files?  Why is IntelliJ locking them?  How can I permanently fix this problem?

Comment: It looks like this issue is fixed in Kotlin 1.4.20

Comment: [Kotlin 1.4.20](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.4.20)  Great, I'll have to give it a try.  I've been waiting for this release for ages.

Comment: For me the problem seems to persist even after upgrading Kotlin to 1.4.20